# Pandas, Filling the missing value

Tags: pandas, missing-data

Here is my question for the with respect to the data frame i have pasted below.

Some values in the the Flight Number column are missing. These numbers are
meant to increase by 10 with each row so 10055 and 10075 need to be put in
place. Fill in these missing numbers and make the column an integer column
(instead of a float column).

```
From_To                    FlightNumber    RecentDelays      Airline
0   LoNDon_paris           10045.0           [23, 47]        KLM(!)
1   MAdrid_miLAN           NaN               []              <Air France> (12)
2   londON_StockhOlm       10065.0           [24, 43, 87]   (British Airways. )
3   Budapest_PaRis         NaN               [13]            12.Air France
4   Brussels_londOn        10085.0           [67, 32]        "Swiss Air"
```

Below is the approach I tried but it didn't give the expected output.

```
for i in range(len(df['FlightNumber'])-1):
    df.iloc[i+1]['FlightNumber']=df.iloc[i]['FlightNumber']+10
```

What could be the correct approach to handle this question, and can someone highlight, what's wrong with my approach.

Comment: `df['FlightNumber'] = df['FlightNumber'].interpolate()`?

Comment: Thank you, but what is wrong with my approach, it should work right ?

Comment: See [Why does assignment fail when using chained indexing?](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing)